# python3 read id3 tags of mp3 files

Tags: python, mp3

Hey i've been looking around for libraries that allow me to read id3 tags of mp3 files. However, i've only found libraries that do not support python3. Can anyone help me extract id3 tags using python3 ? I am currently on a project and this issue is holding me back, big time !

Comment: Maybe this will work ? https://code.google.com/p/stagger/

Answer (score 2):

A port of mutagen (from python 2.x to >=3.3) can be found here:

https://github.com/LordSputnik/mutagen